# Use List.ToLookup()

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a List like the following:

```
var products = new List<Product>
{
    new Product { Id = 1, Category = "Electronics", Value = 15.0 },
    new Product { Id = 2, Category = "Groceries", Value = 40.0 },
    new Product { Id = 3, Category = "Garden", Value = 210.3 },
    new Product { Id = 4, Category = "Pets", Value = 2.1 },
    new Product { Id = 5, Category = "Electronics", Value = 19.95 },
    new Product { Id = 6, Category = "Pets", Value = 5.50 },
    new Product { Id = 7, Category = "Electronics", Value = 250.0 },
};
```

I want to group by category and get the **sum** of 'Values' belonging to that category..
Example: Electronics: 284.95

While I can do this in some other way, I want to learn usage of Look-Up.

Is it possible to get these 2 values (category and Value) in a Look-Up? If yes, How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably want to use [`ToDictionary()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx) instead of `ToLookup`

```
var dict = products
    .GroupBy(p => p.Category)
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Sum(p => p.Value));

foreach(var item in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

Comment: There are multiple items with the same key in the List - a Dictionary won't work.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin Sure it will, there's a `GroupBy` before the `ToDictionary` call.

Comment: @hvd My mistake - I read the first line and was confused about why a Dictionary would be more correct than the Lookup the OP wants to learn about.

Comment: Thanks! This is very clean.. Though I wanted to learn Lookup, ToDictionary suited best for my question, I think..

Comment: @ViV: yeah, it seemed like a dictionary would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 19):

When you retrieve by key from a Lookup, it behaves just like a grouping, so you can do things like this:

```
var productLookup = products.ToLookup(p => p.Category);
var electronicsTotalValue = productLookup["Electronics"].Sum(p => p.Value);
var petsTotalValue = productLookup["Pets"].Sum(p => p.Value);
//etc

var totalValue = products.Sum(p => p.Value);
// I wouldn't use the Lookup here, the line above makes more sense and would execute faster
var alsoTotalValue = productLookup.Sum(grp => grp.Sum(p => p.Value));
```

Comment: Thanks!.. Just curious.. Can I embed the second statement in the first one? Otherwise, I will need to loop through productLookup to get sum of all categories..

Comment: @ViV You can, but then you'll be recreating a lookup every time you call it.  I've added a few more examples of how you can extract various totals, but for some of them it makes more sense to skip the Lookup.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `Lookup`. You can do this with just a query:

```
var results =
    from p in products
    group p by p.Category into g
    select new
    {
        Category = g.Key,
        TotalValue = g.Sum(x => x.Value)
    };
```

Comment: `ToLookup` is a part of LINQ too.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
var result = products
   .ToLookup(key => key.Category, val => val.Value)
   .Select(key => new KeyValuePair<string, double>(key.Key, key.Sum()));
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Perhaps you can add more details, to explain better the most important parts of your answer. Have a read of [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information. Also, once you get more reputation, you will be able to post this as a comment rather than an answer, which would be more appropriate.